# Fix tag indentation in 'align'

Tags: align, aligned

I have the following equations (see latex below):

[image]

My problem is that tag (1) is between the 2 lines, whereas I would like it to be aligned with the 2nd line. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Latex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\begin{align}
&\begin{aligned}
   \sum_{t = 0}^T&{(t + d_{i, m_i}) \cdot s_{i, m_i, t}} \leq \sum_{t = 0}^T{t \cdot s_{j, m_j, t}}, \forall (i, j) \in A,\\
   &\forall m_i \in M_i, \forall m_j \in M_j
\end{aligned}\\
&\text{Test to see that aligned with start of 1st equation}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
a+b=c
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
& \sum_{t = 0}^T  {(t + d_{i, m_i}) \cdot s_{i, m_i, t}} \leq \sum_{t = 0}^T{t \cdot s_{j, m_j, t}}, \forall (i, j) \in A,  \notag \\
& \phantom{\sum_{t = 0}^T}\forall m_i \in M_i, \forall m_j \in M_j                                                                 \\
& \text{Test to see that aligned with start of 1st equation}
\end{align}
\begin{equation}
a+b=c
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\sum_{t = 0}^T & {(t + d_{i, m_i}) \cdot s_{i, m_i, t}} \leq \sum_{t = 0}^T{t \cdot s_{j, m_j, t}}, \forall (i, j) \in A, \notag \\
               & \forall m_i \in M_i, \forall m_j \in M_j                                                                        \\
               & \text{Test to see that aligned with start of 1st equation}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, this indeed helps with the tag, but my idea was to still have 'Test ...' aligned with the start of the first equation (hence the reason for '&\sum...'). Is it possible to combine those 2 alignments?

Comment: @Revirator I have update my answer. You can use `\phantom`.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You want a `t`op `aligned`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
&\begin{aligned}[t]
   \sum_{t = 0}^T & (t + d_{i, m_i}) \cdot s_{i, m_i, t} \leq 
   \sum_{t = 0}^T t \cdot s_{j, m_j, t} , \forall (i, j) \in A,\\
   &\forall m_i \in M_i, \forall m_j \in M_j
\end{aligned}\\
&\text{Test to see that aligned with start of 1st equation}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd move `\forall(i,j)\in A` to the second line, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and suggestion. I will also try that.